# lo_create(0) how to use with insert query

Tags: sql, postgresql, blob, bytea

```
insert into hospital_image 
select 'HospitalImage', 
       lo_from_bytea(1,decode('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA3ADcAAD','base64')),
       'jpg',
       '123'
where not exists (select null from pg_largeObject where loid=1);
```

---

```
CREATE TABLE hospital_image ( 
   key character varying(30) NOT NULL, 
   image oid NOT NULL,
   mime_type character varying(30) NOT NULL, 
   version numeric(8,0) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT 
      pk_hospital_image PRIMARY KEY (key)
) WITH ( OIDS=FALSE );

 ALTER TABLE
    hospital_image OWNER TO postgres;
```

---

Here in the above Statement we are supplying the `loid` manually as 1. Instead we want to get the `loid` dynamically using `lo_create(0)`. When I use `lo_create(0)` as per [the Postgres docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/lo-funcs.html), Iget an exception.

I used both `lo_creat(-1)` and `lo_create(0)`. Both doesn't work. It is saying `loid` exists already. how to use the above functions in my query.

---

My SQL statement for including a variable OID is:

```
INSERT INTO hospital_image (key, image, mime_type, version)
VALUES ('MainLogoImage99999',
        lo_from_bytea(lo_create(0),
                      decode('/9j4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA3ADcAAD',
                      'base64'))‌​,
        'jpg',
        123);
```

The error message is:

```
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (oid)=(34773) already exists.
```

Comment: insert into hospital_image select 'MainLogoImage99999', 
lo_from_bytea(lo_create(-1),decode('/erewreerregrefgrege','base64')),'jpg','123';

Comment: CREATE TABLE hospital_image
(
  key character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  image oid NOT NULL,
  mime_type character varying(30) NOT NULL,
  version numeric(8,0) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT pk_hospital_image PRIMARY KEY (key)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE hospital_image
  OWNER TO postgres;

Comment: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index"
DETAIL:  Key (oid)=(4294967295) already exists.
********** Error **********

Comment: select lo_creat(-1)  returning oid of 35608 but when i use in the insert statement i am getting error that 35609 already exists. I dont know .

Comment: insert into static_image select 'MainLogoImage99999', 
lo_from_bytea(max(loid::bigint),decode('/erewreerregrefgrege','base64')),'jpg','123';ERROR:  column "loid" does not exist
LINE 2: lo_from_bytea(max(loid::bigint),decode('/erewreerregrefgrege...
                          ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: column "loid" does not exist
SQL state: 42703
Character: 74

Comment: please sweep up comments and try query in my answer

Comment: i want an insert query as given the table structure which i dont want to provide loid dynamically.in an insert of statement lo_creat(-1) or lo_create(0) is not working. how to use lo_creat(-1) in the insert statement. Can you please help us to write me one quey for this one ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `lo_creat(-1)` (the argument doesn't matter) and `lo_create(0)` will create a new large object and return its OID.

`lo_create(-1)` is the same as `lo_create(4294967295)` – OIDs are unsigned 4-byte integers.

`lo_from_bytea` *also* creates a new large object, so if you pass it the result from `lo_create`, it complains that it cannot create a large object with the same number again.

Just pass `0` instead of `lo_create(0)` as the first argument to `lo_from_bytea`.

Comment: i checked that too.No it wont happen like that.lo_create gives you an oid which doesn't exist before.But for me it is giving every time the same error. in an insert statement i want to supply the oid from the functions of postgres like lo_creat(-1) or lo_create(0)

Comment: i have given a table structure. can you help me to write a insert query for the above table structure. using dynamically supply loid  with the help of postgres functions

Comment: How *exactly* does the code look? In your question you use a constant 1. In reality you'd do something like `myoid := lo_create(0);`, then write the large object, then insert `myoid` into the table.

Comment: INSERT INTO hospital_image(
            key, image, mime_type, version)
    VALUES ('MainLogoImage99999', lo_from_bytea(myoid := lo_create(0),decode('/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEA3ADcAAD','base64')),  
   'jpg', 123);

Comment: when i executed above statement i got following error                                                                                    ERROR:  positional argument cannot follow named argument
LINE 3: ...oImage99999', lo_from_bytea(myoid := lo_create(0),decode('/9...
                                                             ^

Comment: ^
********** Error **********

ERROR: positional argument cannot follow named argument
SQL state: 42601
Character: 141
Please help me how to get out of this error.

Comment: Remove the `myoid :=` from the insert statement.

Comment: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index"
DETAIL:  Key (oid)=(34773) already exists.
********** Error **********

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pg_largeobject_metadata_oid_index"
SQL state: 23505
Detail: Key (oid)=(34773) already exists.

Comment: if i use the lo_create(0) i got the following above error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163889/discussion-between-ravi-and-laurenz-albe).

Comment: I think I have finally understood your problem. See the corrected answer.

Comment: yes you are right. After going through postgres docs,you are right.